# search and replace part of string in file

Tags: bash, shell, search, replace

I have a file that looks like this.

```
/n01/mysqlarch1/mysql-bin.000011
/n01/mysqlarch1/mysql-bin.000012
/n01/mysqlarch1/mysql-bin.000013
/n01/mysqlarch2/mysql-bin.000014
/n01/mysqlarch2/mysql-bin.000015
/n01/mysqlarch2/mysql-bin.000016
```

I want to be able to search for both mysqlarch1 and mysqlarch2 and replace with mysqldata1.

Therefore the file would end up looking like...

```
/n01/mysqldata1/mysql-bin.000011
/n01/mysqldata1/mysql-bin.000012
/n01/mysqldata1/mysql-bin.000013
/n01/mysqldata1/mysql-bin.000014
/n01/mysqldata1/mysql-bin.000015
/n01/mysqldata1/mysql-bin.000016
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed can do the job:

```
sed 's/mysqlarch[12]/mysqldata1/g' file
/n01/mysqldata1/mysql-bin.000011
/n01/mysqldata1/mysql-bin.000012
/n01/mysqldata1/mysql-bin.000013
/n01/mysqldata1/mysql-bin.000014
/n01/mysqldata1/mysql-bin.000015
/n01/mysqldata1/mysql-bin.000016
```